# Drupal 8 - Facebook Social Login

Tags: facebook, authentication, drupal-8

I've problem when I try to login with Facebook:
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider::getResourceOwner() must be an instance of League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken, null given, called in /var/www/html/modules/contrib/social_auth_facebook/src/FacebookAuthManager.php on line 53 in League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getResourceOwner() (line 765 of /var/www/html/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php) #0 /var/www/html/modules/contrib/social_auth_facebook/src/FacebookAuthManager.php(53): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getResourceOwner(NULL) #1 /var/www/html/modules/contrib/social_auth/src/Controller/OAuth2ControllerBase.php(253): Drupal\social_auth_facebook\FacebookAuthManager->getUserInfo() #2 /var/www/html/modules/contrib/social_auth_facebook/src/Controller/FacebookAuthController.php(80): Drupal\social_auth\Controller\OAuth2ControllerBase->processCallback() #3 [internal function]: Drupal\social_auth_facebook\Controller\FacebookAuthController->callback() #4 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(582): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() #6 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure)) #7 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) #8 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() #9 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #10 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #11 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #12 /var/www/html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #13 /var/www/html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #14 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #15 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #16 /var/www/html/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #17 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(693): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #18 /var/www/html/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #19 {main}.

Someone can help me?

drupal/social_api, drupal/social_auth, drupal/social_auth_facebook, league/oauth2-client

Comment: `Someone can help me?` isn't a valid SO question. You should probably post some code that produces this error.

Answer (score 0):

I've update all libraries to dev, but the problem still remain

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider::getResourceOwner() must be an instance of League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken, null given, called in /var/www/html/modules/contrib/social_auth_facebook/src/FacebookAuthManager.php on line 53 in League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getResourceOwner()